# PostgreSQL: column "BOOLEAN_VALUE" is of type numeric but expression is of type boolean Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I was trying to insert a new data into both database server.
This one works in Oracle 11g but does not work in PostgreSQL 9+.
I cannot trace the issue as the error says:

**column "BOOLEAN_VALUE" is of type numeric but expression is of type boolean  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.**

The column is nullable and in codes below, we do not set any data.

```
Table Def:(Numeric)
"BOOLEAN_VALUE" NUMBER(1,0)

Domain:
@Column(name = "BOOLEAN_VALUE")
public Boolean getBooleanValue() {
    return booleanValue;
}

public void setBooleanValue(Boolean booleanValue) {
    this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
}

How data insertion:
MyData myData = new MyData();
myData.setMoneyValue("$ 120")
myServiceRepository.save(myData);
```

We did passing 0 or 1 as default value but none has worked.
Hope someone can give me some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL do not auto-cast int to boolean automatically, eventually you can create your own cast function.

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createcast.html

Comment: Thank you. The solution we did is we just changed the column definition from Numeric to Boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

For hibernate 6 you can annotate the jdbc type to integer

```
@JdbcTypeCode(Types.INTEGER)
```

private boolean booleanColumn;